# perl one liner to search for a pattern

Tags: perl, design-patterns

I have a text file like

```
Hi
how are you
<blank>
<blank>
abcd
<blank>
defgh
opqr
<blank>
```

I want to print all lines that have the pattern like "some text"blankblank"some text"
like

```
how are you
<blank>
<blank>
abcd
```

I am thinking about using join and then search for the pattern. But I am not sure how to do it. (By blank I mean empty line)

Comment: How should `foo BLANK BLANK bar BLANK BLANK moo BLANK BLANK mar` be handled?

Comment: Should it print the whole thing, or should the middle two blank lines be removed?

Comment: It should print the whole thing

Comment: Good, that's what I assumed in my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Blank line: `/^(?:(?!\n)\s)*\n/m`
- Non-blank line: `/^.*\S.*\n/m`

So you want to print all instances of:

```
 /
    ^
    (?:
       .*\S.*\n
       (?: (?:(?!\n)\s)*\n ){2}
    )+
    .*\S.*\n
 /mx
```

As a lone liner:

```
 perl -0777ne'print /^(?:.*\S.*\n(?:(?:(?!\n)\s)*\n){2})+.*\S.*\n/mg' file
```

---

If all your blank lines contain no whitespace, you can simplify some:

- Blank line: `/^\n/m`
- Non-blank line: `/^.+\n/m`

```
 perl -0777ne'print /^(?:.+\n\n\n)+.+\n/mg' file
```

Comment: Added a simpler but less flexible solution. [ Making trailing whitespace significant is yuck! but it looks far more impressive :) ]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question. What I think you're asking is how you can match 2 consecutive lines that have the same text ("some text") and print those.

to do that you could do something like this

assume that the file is stored as a string in $file

```
print "$1\n$1" while ($file =~ /(.*)(?=\n\1(?:\n|$))/mg);
```

.* = matches anything, grabs up as much is it can

() = capturing group, stores .* to $1 in this case

(?= ... ) = look ahead, so that that part of the string can be used in the next match

\1 = whatever was captured in the first capturing group (i.e $1)

(?: ... ) = non-capturing group